# Creating joomla vendor panel

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, fof

I am new in Joomla component development

I am trying to create multi vendor site like `bookmyshow`.

And I am confused what should I do.

Should I add some fields in `#__users` table like `isVendor`

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to start with reading the documentation.

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component

Answer (score 2):

First, you should learn how to make a Joomla component as @Nagarjun mentioned in his answer. Secondly, you must not add fields to `#__users` table because it will be overwritten by future Joomla updates.

If you want to add extra fields during user registration then you must use `user profile plugin` and add extra fields. It comes pre-installed with Joomla. Or you can also create one yourself. Refer the following link:

1. https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin
2. http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/user-profile/copy-user-profile-plugin - there are 3 steps given for joomla 2.5 but will work for 3x as well.
3. You can use also some third-party extensions like Community Builder, Joom Profile, etc

Hope this helps.